# history.push('/somePath') not working, confused by async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am working on a React/Redux excercise. It works for the most part, but I'm having trouble with the useHistory hook. I have a login form that receives a username and password, then it sets a token in the browser local storage. `login()` is a POST fetch request that works and sets the storage successfully. Then I have a Home component that checks for the token. If there's a token, the page should load, if there's no token, it should redirect to the login page. The problem is  `history.push()` is executing before my token is set, thus sending me back to the login form. To make things even worse, the token actually gets set, but only AFTER the -undesirably early- redirect to the login form. If I try to log in again, it works, but only because the token was already there. So to make the question short, how can I make `history.push()` wait for the token before redirecting?

Here's my form submission function:

```
const handleSubmit =  e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.login(state.userName, state.password); // This sets the token
    history.push('/home'); // This is happening before the token is set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if login is an async function you can try this

```
const handleSubmit =  e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.login(state.userName, state.password)
    .then(history.push('/home')); //waits until promise resolves
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I get `TypeError: props.login(...) is undefined`